# Get a part of a text into a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a .txt file with a content that is delimited by a blank line.

Eg.

```
Question1  
What is your favourite colour?

Question2  
What is your hobby?

Question3  
What kind of music do you like?
```

...and so on.

I would like to put each of the text questions into an array.

I tried this

```
$path=".\Documents\Questions.txt"  
$shareArray= gc $path
```

But it gives me every line into a variable.

Can someone give me a tip?

Thanks

Comment: So you want each item in the array to be two lines (the question number + the question itself)?

Comment: Yes, so that $Question1 to be "Question1 <br/> What is your favourite colour?"

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach which can handle multiline questions and doesn't need a seperating blank line. The split is `^Question` but this text is not excluded. Output is to Out-Gridview.

```
## LotPings  2016-11-26
$InFile = ".\Questions.txt"

## prepare Table 
$Table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$col = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "QuestionNo",([string])
$Table.columns.add($col)
$col = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "QuestionBody",([string]) 
$Table.columns.add($col)

## prepare RegEx for the split
$Delimiter = [regex]'Question'
$Split     = "(?!^)(?=$Delimiter)"

(Get-Content $InFile -Raw) -split $Split |
  ForEach-Object {
    If ($_ -match '(?smi)^(?<QuestionNo>Question\d+)( *)(?<QuestionBody>.*)$') {
      $Row = $Table.Newrow()
      $Row.QuestionNo = $matches.QuestionNo.Trim()
      $Row.QuestionBody = $matches.QuestionBody.Trim()
      $Table.Rows.Add($Row)
    } else {Write-Host "no Match"}
  }
$Table | Out-Gridview
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array, you could filter on whether the lines have `?` at the end or not:

```
$Questions = Get-Content $path |Where-Object {$_.Trim() -match '\?$'}
```

---

If you want to store the questions by the preceding name, you could use a hashtable.

Start by reading the file as a single string, then split by two consecutive line breaks:

```
$Blocks = (Get-Content $path -Raw) -split '\r?\n\r?\n' |ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

If you want both lines in each array item, you can stop here.

Otherwise split each block into a "question name" and "question" part, use those to populate your hashtable:

```
$Questions = @{}
$Blocks |ForEach-Object {
    $Name,$Question = $_ -split '\r?\n'
    $Questions[$Name.Trim()] = $Question
}
```

Now you can access the questions like:

```
$Questions['Question1']
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

other solution 1

```
select-string -Path "C:\temp\test.txt" -Pattern "Question[0-1]*" -Context 0,1 | 
    % {$_.Context.PostContext} | 
        out-file "c:\temp\result.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution 2

```
$template=@"
{Question*:Question1}  
{Text:an example of question?}

{Question*:Question2}  
{Text:other example of question with Upper and digits 12} 
"@

gc "C:\temp\test.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | select Text
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution 3

```
gc "C:\temp\test.txt" | ?{$_ -notmatch 'Question\d+' -and $_ -ne ""  }
```